# Can every planar graph be represented as a set of regions on the grid

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Given a planar graph, can you draw a set of connected regions on a grid such that two cells are adjacent if they touch vertically or horizontally, and two regions $A,B$ are adjacent if $A$ has a cell $a$ that is adjacent to a cell $b\in B$.
The converse is clearly true.
Here is a planar graph:

[image]

Here is the grid representation of the graph:

[image]

The grid drawing can obviously be much smaller.
So my question is can every planar graph be represented in such a way?

Comment: Take
$$\varepsilon = \dfrac{1}{100} \times \min\{ d(s,w) \mid s \text{vertex and $w$ dege that does not contain }s\}.$$

Then draw a grid with squares of size $\varepsilon \times \varepsilon$ over your graph, and number each square with the number of the region its middlepoint belong to.  I think it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### If the entire grid must be filled

In an entirely filled rectangular grid, you will not be able to draw connected regions $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with adjacencies $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,1)$. (That is, the cycle graph $C_5$.)

This configuration is easy to draw with regions that are *not* grid-aligned; however, it cannot be done without creating a point where all five regions meet. Such a point cannot exist in the grid: all points in the grid are adjacent to at most four cells, which are part of at most four regions.

To carry out the same argument more carefully, let's look closely at the boundary of region $1$ in a hypothetical grid drawing. This boundary is made up of segments that are edges between cells of the grid. Some of those edges are borders with region $2$, some of those edges are borders with region $5$, and some might be boundaries of the grid. We can consider several cases:

- Suppose a border with region $2$ meets a border with region $5$ at a point. Around that point, there are $4$ square cells (from region $1$, region $2$, region $5$, and some region that is either one of these or a fourth region). The adjacencies between those square cells create either a $C_3$ or $C_4$ subgraph in the graph, which does not exist in the graph we're trying to draw.
- Suppose this doesn't happen: either because region $1$ touches the side of the grid in two places separating $2$ from $5$, or because region $2$ is entirely on the inside and region $5$ entirely on the outside, or vice versa. This means that there is no way to get from region $2$ to region $5$ without going through region $1$. But that's also not true of the graph we're trying to draw, where we can go from $2$ to $5$ via $3$ and $4$.

Either way, we get a contradiction, so a drawing of $C_5$ in the grid does not exist.

### If we can leave holes in the grid

This problem is resolved if you are allowed to leave some blank space in the grid which is not part of any region. In this case, any planar graph can be represented.

Here's just an intuitive argument. Take any actual pixel drawing of the graph, such as the one in the question:

[image: the same drawing as in the question]

To each vertex, assign the region consisting of the black pixels representing that vertex and extending halfway along each edge. Leave the white space unfilled.

Comment: By a region I mean one cell or a collection of cells. The cycle graph of order 5 can very easily be drawn in the grid.

Comment: Not unless you're allowing yourself some tricks you haven't mentioned in the question. It can easily be done if regions don't have to be connected, but in that case it's not a planar drawing any more.

Comment: A region is a vertex, so why won't it be planar?

Comment: In a planar drawing (that is, in a planar drawing where we're representing a vertex of a graph by a *region* of the plane - planar map might be the better term), all regions have to be connected.

Comment: Ok, so is every planar graph a planar map?

Comment: "Is" is the wrong word, but yes, every planar graph can be represented by regions in the plane. Not every planar graph can be represented by regions in the grid, however - in particular, $C_5$ cannot! I have given you a proof, and I can make the proof more formal if you like, but I suspect you think it can be done just because you haven't tried doing it.

Comment: Thank you, can you please make the proof more formal.

Comment: Done. The next time you claim that something can "very easily be done", I recommend doing it: it is very easy to make mistakes in math if you decide that something is very easy and it turns out to be impossible.

Comment: What I meant was that you can leave blank space sorry for the misunderstanding. How would you go about proving it if we allow blank space?

Comment: I've added an intuitive argument. To make it formal, you'd want to specify a sufficiently small edge length of the grid so that you don't get unwanted adjacencies.